# Why can I not comment on a post

Tags: discussion

Why can I not add comments on a post? It says I have to have 50 reputation points. I looked under reputation and it says I do not need any points to comment, please help.

Comment: You don't need any points to comment on your own questions and answers. To comment on anyone else's, you do need 50 rep.

Comment: Reference https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

Answer (score 5):

You don't have enough reputation to comment on **other people's** questions/answers.

Per the [FAQ](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment);

> **Privilege Type:** Communication Privilege
>   **Awarded At:** 50 Reputation
>
> Please note that you can always comment on your own posts, and any
>   part of your questions. However, ***commenting on other people's posts is
>   a privilege.***

If you want to post general comments, you'll need at least 50 reputation points. This is to stop "drive-by" commenters from posting worthless comments on questions and answers that they've found through google.

---

For reference, the quickest way to get 50 points is by posting a high quality answer or asking a question about a popular recent film.